# Simple Question! Trying to install Xubuntu! Which file do I extract in WinRAR to do so?

Tags: xubuntu

OK

Here goes

Downloaded Ubuntu - not working (ISO error?)  OK - skip that - try Xubuntu instead - OK - downloads - OK needs me to extract something in WinRAR - OK - not at all clear what to extract?  Can't find help in forums?  Seems basic question??

HALP?@!QQ?

Answer (score 3):

- you do NOT use RAR.
- you check the ISO ([md5checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)) and burn the contents of the ISO to either a DVD or onto an USB  with an appropriate tool.

Comment: what's an appropriate tool?

Comment: http://www.isotousb.com/   ??

Comment: am i doing it rite